# Listen for JUnit Test Suite Failure

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I would like to listen to JUnit test suite failure.  I am able to listen to test failure, and @Before/@After failure by implementing a [RunListener](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html).  However, this doesn't seem to get called when the @BeforeClass/@AfterClass annotated methods fail.  Is there some other type of listener that gets notified when those methods fail (e.g. raise an exception)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try experimenting with a MethodRule: http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/MethodRule.html

PS: take note that it's deprecated...